# How can I draw a quadratic curve that is going through a certain control point

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, quadratic-curve

I'm trying to draw a quadratic curve that has movable control points on the canvas. Everything is okay but how can I draw a quadratic curve that is going through a certain control point?

I tried this:

```js
const startPoints = [0,0];
const controlPoints = [100, 40];
const endPoints = [200, 200];

ctx.moveTo(...startPoints);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(...controlPoints, ...endPoints);
ctx.stroke();
```

It draws a quadratic curve like this (purple circles are the points):

[image]

> the middle circle is the control point of the curve.

But what I want to draw is like this:

[image]

I mean, I want the quadratic curve to go through the control point. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you've mis-interpreted what a "control point" actually is in a quadratic curve. The control point is used to determine the amount and direction of deflection the curve will have - it isn't meant to lie on the curve.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/983875/equation-of-a-curved-line-that-passes-through-3-points

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers. I've solved the problem with your helps.